# How to define webservice interface flexibility to adapt any changes

Tags: java, web-services, interface

I am developing a application which includes 2 modules:

- **Server**: written by java and publish webservice using **SOAP**
- **Client**: written by C# and call webservice of server

I have a problem at Server when I add a property into **BeanObject** published to webservice. I must synchronize BeanObject at **Client** again.

Is there any way to keep webservice interface between **Server** and **Client** in case **BeanObject** is changed some properties.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your webservice accepts one string parameter and returns one string as result then you can exchange any data you wish by string encoding convention.

a odbc/jdbc/oledb databaseconnection string works like this.

i use these strings to transfer xml between mobile device and server

```
 String xmlResult = myWebservice.getItems(xmlRquestParameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Microsoft Dynamics CRM works. It is very flexible to change anything you want without modifying webservice interface.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327974.aspx)

I will apply the way in my APL (a large and complicated APL), so that I need a standand pattern to prove that it can work.